# Mocking Highcharts (w/ Exporting) for Jest Unit Testing

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, jestjs, enzyme

I am working on a React project that I am testing using Jest.
Our application uses Highcharts to render data visulaizations on our views, but I am having an issue when it comes to using one of Highcharts plugin modules "exporting" that is used for capturing the dataURL of the svg Highcharts has already rendered.

Everything unfortunately works beautifully when it comes to actually running the application and seeing everything work, but since unit testing is a big requirement  I am now stuck on this mocking aspect.

My component imports highcharts and it's module like

```
import Highcharts, { Chart } from 'highcharts';
import addExporting from 'highcharts/js/modules/exporting.src.js'
addExporting(Highcharts);
```

I created a genMockFromModule in **mocks**/highcharts.ts

```
const highcharts: any = jest.genMockFromModule(`highcharts`);
highcharts.getOptions = () => ({ plotOptions: {}, exporting: {} });
module.exports = highcharts;
```

I tried in my test file (**tests**/components/Chart.ts)

```
jest.mock('highcharts', () => ({
  Chart: jest.fn(),
  setOptions: jest.fn(),
  seriesTypes: {},
}));
jest.mock('highcharts/js/modules/exporting.src.js', () => jest.fn() )
```

Seems whatever I try, I always get this issue:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined
>
> ```
>   16 |
> > 18 | addExporting(Highcharts);
>      | ^
>   19 |
>
>   at node_modules/highcharts/js/modules/exporting.src.js:49:23
>   at node_modules/highcharts/js/modules/exporting.src.js:1760:3
> ```

Without addExporting module I can't figure out how to mock the other highcharts functionality such as

```
if(this.chartRef) {
    this.chartRef.destroy()
}
```

Comment: Could you share a simplified package with your app and instructions on how to start it? It will be easier to check what's going on there.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-evvwef I don't think I set it up correctly, I use typescript and webpack in my project, but this is a rough layout using jsx ... it doesn't seem to run on stackblitz buuuut thats essentially how its setup.

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, it's hard to analyze it in stackblitz editor. Could you prepare a package with the project to run it locally, see the chart and run tests?